# Extract data of a cell after colon

Tags: excel, text-extraction

my data looks like this:

```
Department code
ABCD : ZERT
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI_1
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI_2
ABCD : ZERT : TYOP
ABCD : ZERT : TYOM
ABCD : ZERT : TYOM : WXCV
```

Basicaly I am looking for a function in excel that will permit me to only extract the last characters placed after the last colon. 
Expected data would look like this :

```
Department code            Expected data
ABCD : ZERT                ZERT
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI         TYUI
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI_1       TYUI_1
ABCD : ZERT : TYUI_2       TYUI_2
ABCD : ZERT : TYOP         TYOP
ABCD : ZERT : TYOM         TYOM
ABCD : ZERT : TYOM : WXCV  WXCV
```

I have tried the function STXT but unfortunatly it is too limited. Anyone have a solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

<sub>Note: I changed the formula entirely after the first two comments below pointed out the original was incorrect. FYI</sub>

Comment: You're losing the T from TYUI_1

Comment: This only works if the number of characters right of the last `:` is the same as the number of characters before the first `:`

Comment: Ah, good calls. I updated the formula. It works for me now.

Comment: Very neat answer now!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you very much !!