# How do I delete text before the last forward slash in a column?

Tags: excel, csv, formula, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with columns that show a filepath. They look like this:

```
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_18.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_17.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_16.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_15.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_14.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_13.jpg
/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_12.jpg
```

I want to remove everything before the last slash so they look like this:

```
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_18.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_17.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_16.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_15.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_14.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_13.jpg
/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_12.jpg
```

Can I do this with a formula or an built-in function? I use OpenOffice.

---

I have tried the `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))` formula but I get a Error:501 on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract data of a cell after colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688983/extract-data-of-a-cell-after-colon)

Comment: This question has come up so much in the past. A recent good solution was provided in the answer linked above. Please search the site before posting a question. `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`

Comment: I get error 501 when trying to use that formula.

Comment: @Oscar is the length of these values always the same or may they change?

Comment: The [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBSTITUTE_function) function definitely works in OO, so just do `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/j/t","")` according to your examples.

Comment: @PLATANIUM They change and some are /a/b/ while others are just /a/. And there are many different directories, /j/t as well as /n/k for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your target string is always the same length:

```
=RIGHT(A1,23) 

Input: /j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg        Output: /jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg
```

If you have variable length strings and always 3 backslashes in filepath:

```
="/" &RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) -FIND("*", SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","*",3), 1))

Input: /j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_1000.jpg      Output: /jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_1000.jpg
```

If you have variable length strings and variable backslashes in filepath:

```
="/" &RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) -FIND("*", SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","*", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","") )), 1))

Input: a/b/c/j/t/jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg   Output: /jtfdsrn-01r_1_1_19.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you if your values dont change there shouldnt be an issue but if so ill look into it.

```
=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND("/";A2;3)-1)
```

Comment: Note if OP uses this answer, they might need to replace the `;` with `,` depending on regional settings

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Wildcard (*/) Without Brackets In Find and Replace